# AWS S3 video playback only working with presigned URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a mp4 video uploaded to S3 with public read enabled for the bucket and object.

If I paste https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/my_folder/my_video.mp4 into a new tab, amazonaws.com never responds, and the request is infinitely waiting for a response.

If I get a preauthenticated url for the same video, and paste it in a new tab, it plays immediately. It seems this is some sort of permissions issue, even though everything is set to be publicly readable. The jpg objects in the same bucket and folder, with the same permissions, load with the direct url, like they are supposed to.

No, the issue is not System defined Content-Type video/mp4 metadata.

I want https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/my_folder/my_video.mp4 to play without any extra steps, like generating a preauthenticated URL. If I am uploading 100 videos to S3, I don't want to have to write and run an script to generate preauthenticated urls for them. I also don't want the url to 'expire'. If I set an object to have public read access, it should be able to be publicly viewable!

How do I get AWS S3 behave like it is supposed to for video?

Comment: "some sort of permissions issue" what does it mean? You need to provide precise and detailed description of issue. Errors?

Comment: No errors. That's why I have to guess. Nothing to go off of.

Answer (score 0):

Although https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/my_folder/my_video.mp4 would just infinitely wait for a response and not throw an error, I happened to notice through experimentation with the preauthenticated url that https://mybucket.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my_folder/my_video.mp4 loads fine.